# Python3: Why does list.append('string') appends to the element of the list not to list itself?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to parse equations as prepared text (eg:"0.035*Vp-31.5"),

extract decimal numbers, 
save them to a list and replace them by 'X' in the equation.
Then return everything ...

Strange output:
('0.035*Vp-31.5', [**'0.03531.5'**])

It is supposed to be:
('X*Vp-X', [**'0.035','31.5'**])

```
def const(eqNo):
    temp = ''
    args = []
    eq = eq_s[eqNo]
    for i in range(len(eq)):
        if eq[i].isdigit():
            temp+=eq[i]
        elif eq[i] == '.':
            temp+=eq[i]
        elif eq[i].isdigit == False:
            if len(temp) != 0:
                args.append(temp)
            temp = ''
    else:
        if len(temp) != 0:
            args.append(temp)
    for j in args:
        eq.replace(j,'X',1)
    return eq, args
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your only problem, but your elif needs some parentheses: `elif eq[i].isdigit() == False:`. Or, more idiomatically, `elif not eq[i].isdigit():`. Or, come to think of it, you already know `isdigit` is false since the `if` condition failed, so I guess you can delete the `elif` condition and just write `else:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with this

```
elif eq[i].isdigit == False:
```

you forgot parenthesis after isdigit, it should be

```
elif eq[i].isdigit() == False:
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes these kind of mistakes take a lot of time((